# Is it necessary to wear kippa to bed or when not moving?

Tags: sleep, standing-sitting, kippa-yarmulka

I have noticed [mention made](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/110372/jewish/Some-Laws-of-Covering-the-Head.htm) of a prohibition of sitting in the house bareheaded when at rest and of the necessity of wearing a head covering at night.

Is there a halachic law deeming it necessary to wear a head covering when sleeping or sitting at rest at home? If so, what are the sources and explanations for these prohibitions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Mishna Berura ([2:11](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49623&st=&pgnum=12&hilite=)) quoted in the linked article brings from the Shaloh Hakadosh that while not required by the strict letter of the law it is considered "midas chassidus" (pious behavior) to cover one's head while sleeping.

Comment: The only mention of hair that I see is a little later on, when M"B mentions that you should not cover your head with a PaRU"K of your hair (I'm guessing this is some kind of toupee?) because others might this is your own hair (ie., you're not wearing any head covering at all).

Comment: @SethJ I am not sure what you mean. SA says one may not walk four amos with uncovered hair and MB adds from Shaloh that even sleeping with a head covering is Midas Chassidus.

Comment: No, it talks about uncovered head. Did I miss something?

Comment: @SethJ What is the difference between uncovered head and uncovered hair?

Comment: Well, women have laws about hair. Depending how you hold, it might matter if a bit of hair is showing. But if we were to follow that for men, a Kippah would have to be much larger than most are.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baldness

Comment: @SethJ It was just my loose translation of "גילוי ראש"; I have edited my answer to head to make it clearer.

Comment: That's all I was saying.  +1